# Does "Submit" make an ipa file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I think when you want to make an .ipa file, you will export the .ipa file you can see in the folder you chose. But when you do "Submit" to submit the app in App Store, you don't get ipa file on your PC directly.

I know ipa file includes the information of the app's data so I think if you submit it means you submit .ipa file but you can't get it on your PC. Is it right? What does "Submit" make and give App Store?

Comment: it might submit the entire archive to the app store where it will be compiled further and resources taken out for app slicing etc

Comment: @user770 I mean the "Submit" in Product->Archive->"Upload to App Store...". I want to know what data (archive file, ipa file, etc) "Upload to App Store..." uploads to App Store.

Answer (score -4):

No submit does't make an ipa file in Xcode.